# Proving that $f(x)=\ln(x)+\sqrt{\frac{C}{x^\alpha}}>0$

Tags: real-analysis

Given $C,\alpha\in(0,1)$ lets define $f(x):= \ln(x)+\sqrt{\frac{C}{x^\alpha}}$. It's easy to prove that $f$ has a global minimum in $x_o=(\frac{\alpha}{2}\sqrt{C})^{2/\alpha}$ and f is decreasing in $(0,x_o)$.

I just need to prove that there's a point $x'\in (0,x_o)$ such that $f(x')\geq 0$.

Comment: Hint: $g(x)=f(e^x)$ is convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\infty
$$
Indeed, if you set
$$
y=\sqrt{C/x^\alpha}
$$
then $x=(C/y^2)^{1/\alpha}$ and the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{y\to\infty}(\ln(C/y^2)^{1/\alpha}+y)=
\lim_{y\to\infty}\left(\frac{\ln C}{\alpha}-\frac{2\ln y}{\alpha}+y\right)=
\lim_{y\to\infty}y\left(\frac{\ln C}{\alpha y}-\frac{2\ln y}{\alpha y}+1\right)=\infty
$$
because
$$
\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{\ln y}{y}=0
$$
is well known.

Comment: Why $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} f(x) = \infty$?. I mean, I know by some experiments that it's true and obviously it implies what I asking for, but I need a prove.

Comment: @YesidFonsecaV. Isn't what follows “the limit becomes” the required proof?

Comment: Mmm I got it now. But, why $\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}-2\ln y/\alpha+y=\infty$ for any $\alpha\in(0,1)$?

Comment: @YesidFonsecaV. I added a step. Basically, $y$ dominates $\ln y$.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the (slick) hint in the comment, use a log identity to write

$f(x)=\ln(xe^{\sqrt{\frac{C}{x^{\alpha }}}})$ and notice that $xe^{\sqrt{\frac{C}{x^{\alpha }}}}\to \infty $ as $x\to 0^+$. Since $\ln$ is strictly increasing, $f(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to 0^+$ as well.

Comment: Why $xe^{\sqrt{\frac{C}{x^\alpha}}}\geq x+\sqrt{\frac{C}{x^\alpha}}$? for $x$ close enough to zero

Comment: @YesidFonsecaV sorry it was a typo, I fixed it.